# Consuming CometD messages with spring webflux

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, cometd

We have a system which publishes messages via cometD.

I wrote a simple java program to establish a connection to the server
then use the bearer token returned from the login to and consume messages

But I want to move this to a Webflux project, but unsure where to start, I can see there is out of box JMS-webflux wrapper, can I use this or is it best to build something similar ?

I'm very new to cometD and have only used simple webflux components,
I can also just use Spring boot, but ideally just like a JmsReceiver or similar

Thanks

Comment: You should clarify how exactly your system would work, especially describing what you are going to do with the CometD messages. You want to send them to another server using WebFlux's client ? You want to return them as a response to a HTTP request, in batches ? You want to return them as an infinite response (e.g. "application/json+stream") ? Do you have a URL for the JMX-WebFlux wrapper ?

Comment: Yes, you are right, probably should be more specific, we have an instance of Salesforce running, and this will trigger an event. So ideally I'll have a spring project (this is probably more important first step than webflux), which will connect and 'do something' with the message (i.e. yet to be decided) . I'm struggling to find a spring cometD bayeaux client example on the web, I found a salesforce library called empConnect which is a plain old java. I've started to build a spring cometD client library. But was hoping to find some examples as I find the documentation a bit light for spring.

Comment: You don't need Spring to get a CometD message and "do something yet to be decided" - all you need is the `BayeuxClient` that CometD provides. If you are more specific on what exactly you have to do with "do something", then I can help.